# How to execute single scenario from two or three scenario in single feature file?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

In my code, I am having multiple scenarios (for every scenario I mentioned with separate tag name) in single feature. In `runner.java` file also I mentioned with tags attribute which scenario alone need to be run, but still its not working last modified scenario alone its running.

I tried in all ways, i.e. with different tag names and changed in runner class still its not working

Comment: Can u clarify on " last modified scenario alone its running"? Also why are u using "scenario outline" instead of a "scenario". The details are being passed in datatable anyways. Is this the complete file or something is omitted?

Comment: Last modified scenario means,which scenario i added at last and this is not my complete code for reference purpose i shown partially but working with this two scenarios only.

Answer (score 1):

because you have mention only one tag in runner file. if you want to execute full feature file then you have to mention feature tag in cucumber option in runner file or all scenario tag should be in cucumber option----tags= {"@Truckdues-Amendment","@Login_and_business_create"}  or {"@Truckdues"}

Comment: yes nitish you are right., but what is my problem is what tag name am specifying in runner file thats not executing..its executing some other scenario- this is my actual problem...Can anybody please clarify on this?